# unable to create a trigger using ' WHEN '

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create trigger info22 after insert on table_info1 for each row 
when( :new.pid < 60 )
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(' thus the given id is less than 60');
  insert into table_info2 values(:new.pid, :new.pname, :new.ploc);
end;
```

when I typed the above query I'm getting a error as

```
ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause
```

Answer (score 4):

when referring to new values you don't need to use a semicolon, because you are doing this, Oracle thinks that you are trying to use a bind variable.
try typing `new.` instead of `:new.` and see if helps.

Comment: please canu elaborate whats bind and use of 'new' keyword

Comment: Sure, the `new` keyword is used to reference the new row entered into the table. a bind variable is a completely different subject, used to improve performance of queries running many times with different values in their variables but maintaining the same structure.
You're welcome to read more about it here - http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html, for example.

Comment: If you've found my answer helpful, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `new`/`old` references in the **WHEN** clause doesn't need a **colon**.

Change:

```
when( :new.pid < 60 )
```

To:

```
when( new.pid < 60 )
```

Comment: thamk you 
can u please elaborate what s  a 'bind'